# Convert VS project from Windows 8.1 to Desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop-application, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I Have a C# Windows 8.1 project on Visual Studio that I would like to convert to a Windows Desktop application.

Is there an easy way to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried a google search on how to convert C# Windows 8.1 project to WinForms

Comment: All I've found is this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx but not sure that this is what I'm looking for.. Was hoping for some microsoft tool to do that for me

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic way. The easiest way is to create two new projects, one is the desktop (WPF) app and the other is shared project. Then move all the code that you can to the shared project. You might need to use a conditional compiling (`#if`).